# HTML Escaping for perl

Tags: html, perl

I have a html code assigned to a perl variable

```
1) my $content;

$content .= qq~<input type='hidden' name='Email' value='~.$ARGS{Email}.qq~' />~;
```

Another one is this:

```
2) <form name="email_form" id="email_form" class="form-inline <% $ARGS{Email} ? 'hide' : '' %>" >
```

How to do mason substitution for these?

For the second one, is this right?

```
<form name="email_form" id="email_form" class="form-inline <% $ARGS{Email} | h ? 'hide' : '' %>" >
```

Comment: i am not getting this question will u explain more

Comment: I meant mason substitution like if there is <% $ARGS{error} %>, it becomes <% $ARGS{error} | h %> in mason substitution. How to do it for the above ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CGI's`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) [`escapeHTML`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#AUTOESCAPING-HTML) or some equivalent

```
use CGI qw(escapeHTML);

$content .= qq~<input type='hidden' name='Email' value='~. escapeHTML($ARGS{Email}) .qq~' />~;
```